# Do we have some placeholders in java for string as we have (?) in SQL prepared statement

Tags: java, replace

Can i have placeholder for String java like we have in sql prepared statements?

Eg Conside that i have `string St = "akkk ? la,ala ? " ,`

now i want to set values of ?  as  i set it in sql prepared statement
 st.setStingValue(1,"akshay");  // do we have something like this?
 St.setStringValue(2,"anjaaa");

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use String.format

```
String st = "akkk %s la,ala %s "; 
String result = String.format(st, "First Val", "Second Val");
```

Alternatively, you can use numeric positions

```
String st = "akkk %1$s la,ala %2$s "; 
String result = String.format(st, "First Val", "Second Val");
```

Answer (score 6):

you can look at this [Class MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Comment: 404 for the above link.

Answer (score 1):

replaceFirst() is bad idea in this case - a first argument is expected to be a regex, if second arg contains sequences that are interpreted as regex processing directives eg. as group references (like '$') you will get an exception in trivial DB operation - depending on data passed to query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variation.

```
 public class SimplePrepareStatement {
    String vars[];
    String query;

    public SimplePrepareStatement(String query) {
        int countVars = StringUtils.countMatches(query, "?");
        vars = new String[countVars];
        this.query = query.replaceAll("\\?", "%s");
    }

    public void setDouble(int i, Double arg0) {
        vars[i-1] = "'"+arg0+"'";
    }

    public void setString(int i, String arg0) {
        vars[i-1] = "'"+arg0+"'";
    }

    public void setObject(int i, String arg0) {
        vars[i-1] = arg0;
    }

    public String getSQL() {
        return String.format(query, vars);
    }
 }
```

**Note! This is not for SQL use, possible SQLinjections, just similiar behavior.**

```
   @Test
public void simplePrepareStatementTest() {
    SimplePrepareStatement st = new SimplePrepareStatement("abc ? abc ?");
    st.setString(1, "a");
    st.setString(2, "b");
    assertEquals("abc 'a' abc 'b'", st.getSQL());
    st.setObject(1, "obj");
    assertEquals("abc obj abc 'b'", st.getSQL());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use replaceFirst of the String to achieve the same effect.
read about it here : http://www.roseindia.net/java/string-examples/string-replacefirst.shtml

Comment: Building a string differently is not the same as using prepared statements, where the values are not part of the query sent to the database